# og:image shows upp blank

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I'm maintaining a WordPress site and for some reason I can't get a thumbnail (the image is there but blank) to the post when I share it on Facebook.

I've checked the facebook debugger but doesn't see any warnings or errors.

For example:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://xboxflickan.se/2013/08/finstamt-sagoberattande-i-brothers-a-tale-of-two-sons/

http://xboxflickan.se/2013/08/finstamt-sagoberattande-i-brothers-a-tale-of-two-sons/

What could be wrong?

Appreciate the help

Kind regards,
/Linus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your page's source - you're setting the og:image property twice.  Once with a plugin and I assume once by directly coding it into your template.

Comment: Twice? I see only og:image once in the code. Very strange, are you sure that you saw it twice?

Comment: I don't see it twice now.  Has anything changed?  Maybe it was a hallucination, but I saw another og:image tag toward the top of the source.